# Radio button group from enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I'm trying to come up with a generic view model and editor template for enum types in a way that possible values are rendered into a radio button group. Let me elaborate.

The VM looks like so

```
public class OptionViewModel<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
   public TEnum SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

I could then create an instance for any enum in my project by writing

```
public enum Numbers { One, Two, Three }

...
NumberOptions = new OptionViewModel<Numbers>();
...
```

and then have that rendered via

```
@model OptionViewModel<TEnum>

@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>())
{
   var selected = value == Model.SelectedValue;

   @Html.RadioButton(value.ToString(), value, selected)
}
```

Unfortunately, the template doesn't even compile, because there is no type 'TEnum', of course.

Is there a better (working) way to do this? I'd really get this level of abstraction, as radio button groups from enums is a fairly common case in my project, and it comes with additional attributes, such as IsVisible, IsEnabled and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the enum values in your view model as strings and create a function that accepts the generic parameters to create the view model.

```
public class OptionViewModel
{
   public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
   public List<string> Values { get; set; }

   public static OptionViewModel Create<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
   {
        var ovm = new OptionViewModel();
        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>())
        {
             ovm.Values.Add(value);
        }
        return ovm;
   }
}
```

In the controller:

```
NumberOptions = OptionViewModel.create<Numbers>();
```

In the view, and if i'm not mistaken mvc forms will return the value in  Model.SelectedValue:

```
@model OptionViewModel

@foreach (var value in model.Values)
{
   var selected = value == Model.SelectedValue;

   @Html.RadioButton(Model.SelectedValue, value, selected)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this in Kotlin.  The following function takes an enum and turns it into a RadioGroup, and a function that allows you to query the selected value:

```
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> enumToViewAndResultGetter(default: T, context: Context): Pair<RadioGroup, (() -> T)>{
    val enumValues = enumValues<T>().toList()
    val radioButtons: List<RadioButton> = enumValues.map { RadioButton(context).apply { text=it.name } }
    val radioGroup = RadioGroup(context).apply { for (v in radioButtons) addView(v)}
    val buttonIdToEnumValue = radioButtons.map{it.id}.zip(enumValues).associate { it }  // Key that this is done AFTER adding buttons to group (as that is when ids are assigned)
    radioGroup.check(enumValues.indexOf(default))
    return Pair(radioGroup) {buttonIdToEnumValue[radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId]!!}
}
```

Which I used in a selection dialog:

```
enum class SortOptions {TIME_ASCENDING, TIME_DESCENDING, SCORE_DESCENDING}
...

val (radioGroup, itemCallback) = enumToViewAndResultGetter(default = sortBy, context = applicationContext)
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(radioGroup)
    .setPositiveButton("Re-Sort") { dialog, id ->
        sortBy = itemCallback()
        reSortItems()
        showToast("Sorted by ${sortBy.name}")
    }
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id -> }
    .create().show()
```