# How to make a group of radio buttons from numbers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to know the best approach to making a group of radio buttons from numbers.  I know that an enum would not work because it is using numbers.  What I would like it to look like is this:

> o 10  o 15 o 20 o 25

I am using this as part of a form for a search

I am getting some great feedback but what I am needing is to make 4 radio buttons that go horizontally across a form.  I am not sure if an array list would work

Perhaps this is more of a html formatting issue as brought up in the comments.

I have tried to build an enum and loop through it using this question and solution from here
 [Radio button group from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835244/radio-button-group-from-enum?rq=1)

I have also tried this solution
https://forums.asp.net/t/1923953.aspx?Custom+MVC+Extension+Methods

neither of them are producing the results that I want but I also am afraid I am making a mountain out of a molehill as well.  That is why I thought I would ask for some advice

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqwcz.png)

Comment: Are you looking to create dynamic radio buttons with the value/text of elements? I'd just use an array/ArrayList and loop over it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Create your radio buttons using HTML, have a property to set to the value of the selected button, and then send that property as part of your model to the backend.

Comment: @StevenByrne I am not sure if an array list would work properly I edited my question

Comment: @Dido  I don't think that is what I would want as that would just create a list

Comment: @jax no, that isn't what would happen.

Comment: Is this more of an HTML/Design question?... could you provide more information on what you are trying to do and what specifically you are having trouble with (along with anything you've tried)

Comment: What is your desired out put, what are you currently getting. Can you add sample code?

Comment: Is your output something related to aligning the Radio buttons in a single line? In that case, you need to write some CSS properties on the radio buttons to achieve the same

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is.  Radio buttons in a single line is [easy](https://jsfiddle.net/zeLrkw05/)

Comment: @Amy Sorry I am just learning.  Sometimes people don't understand things as quickly as others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the CSS Style

```
float: left;
```

Just give to to your elements, but not the last.

Answer (score 0):

I am rather embarrassed but as Amy pointed out in the comments this is quite easy.  I was indeed making a mountain out of a molehill

The code is as follows and I hope it will help someone else

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="editList" value="10"/>10
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="editList" value="15"/>15
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="editList" value="20"/>20
</label>
```

This still doesn't produce a horizontal grouping but I am sure it is in the css as is in the comments